# Match spring controller to domain

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc

I don't know how to describe it in a better way, as in the headline, because I really don't know what I'm actually looking for.

I have my spring app and the main Servlet matches the root. Here is the used servlet mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>shop</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And the app it self is deployed as root app.

So the Problem is now, when I try to access the domain via example.com it does not work and I get a 404 not found error. Only when I use the following url: example.com/ ... tara ... it works as expected.

I know that is a really basic question, but since I do not know what I have to search for. I couldn't find any thing to solve this problem.

Thanks for any kind of solution to solve this issue. :)

Comment: This can be any one of a number of issues. Without more information, I can only recommend that you debug your dispatcher servlet to ensure that your request is even making it to Spring. This way you can focus on the Spring side or the Web Server/Container/web.xml side.

Comment: Which web container are you using? Tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your answers. I know that question is a bit old, but for all who had the same problem.

Here you can find the solution for xml and java config:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler

If you add this xml tag or override the java config method it works, that your web app can respond to '/' urls :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse application context root with URL root.  Remember java web containers are not the same thing as an HTTP server.

If you're using a container such as Tomcat to deploy the app and want the app to tie to the root URL, you're going to have to use an http server such as Apache HTTP to set up a virtual host.

Would start reading this documentation:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html

If you want to set up a virtual host for your web app.

Answer (score 0):

/ is a special url matching pattern meaning the "default" servlet. If you want your servlet to serve all requests, use /*. The default servlet is called when no other match is found to serve static content and list folders, which is probably not what you want here. Not sure about it, but the default servlet might require the leading slash.